# LNK2001 - unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2010, interop, c++-cli

I know this is a common error (in Visual Studio C++), with a rather wide range of causes, but I *think* I've ruled out the relevant suggestions from [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) - I've linked in the .lib file where these things ought to be getting defined (it's the only .lib linked by the example app I have which uses the same .h file - the basic point of what I'm doing here is to try and wrap that .lib as a .dll so I can use it with C#). The fact the example app compiles okay despite only including that one .lib and no .cpp corresponding to the .h surely means that the .lib defines whatever's declared in the .h (right?)...

It might help if I could even read this error with any confidence. Is JSONRPCHandlerErrorType the unresolved symbol? What are all those @ signs and seemingly random letters doing in there?

I'm fairly sure I must be missing something obvious. Many thanks if you can help me figure out what, and apologies if I'm not giving enough information to go on or I'm missing something that should have been clear from previous threads about this...

`Error  1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: enum JSONRPCHandlerErrorType __thiscall JSONRPCHandler::handleRequest(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?handleRequest@JSONRPCHandler@@$$FQAE?AW4JSONRPCHandlerErrorType@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) C:\Users\Fergus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\libspark\libspark\ManagedLibspark.obj ManagedLibspark`

For what it's worth, here's the bit of the .h file about JSONRPCHandlerErrorType:

```
typedef enum {
    JSONRPCHandlerErrorNone = 0,
    JSONRPCHandlerErrorParsing,
    JSONRPCHandlerErrorBadDocument,
    JSONRPCHandlerErrorNoIdSpecified,
    JSONRPCHandlerErrorNoObjectNameSpecified,
    JSONRPCHandlerErrorNoMethodNameSpecified,
    JSONRPCHandlerErrorNoParamsSpecified

} JSONRPCHandlerErrorType;
```

Comment: It is **not** complaining about that enum.  It can't find a *function*, handleRequest().  There's nothing relevant in your question that helps us help you.  Read through that linked question again now that you know it is a function.

Comment: Thank you Hans. It looks like the form of that function taking only a string must be undefined in the .lib, despite appearing in the .h; the example app only uses the version which takes both a string and a callback function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant helpfully explained, the unresolved symbol in question was `handleRequest(class std::basic_string)`. The linker couldn't find this particular form of this function in the .lib where I was expecting to find it; why it's declared in the .h file, I don't know, but as it happens it's not crucial to what I'm trying to do anyway. There's another form of the function that takes both a string and a callback function, and that is adequate for my purposes.

My problem, then, was a [declared and undefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/673730) all along; I erroneously ruled this out because the example app used the same function and compiled fine - but it used a *different version* of the function, and if I'd been able to mentally parse what the verbose error message was telling me, I could probably have seen that.